# IPtables remove every chain except one

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm aware that it's possible to flush the iptables using `iptables -F` or `iptables -X`, however, is it possible to flush the iptables except for one crucial chain/rule?

Answer (score 0):

dump the rules to file with

```
iptables-save > file
```

delete all rules except the ones you want to keep,
restore the rules that were not deleted, overwriting the current iptables rules.

```
iptables-restore < file
```

or just flush all rules and create the one you want to have.

When you dump the rules to file you will see they are all in format resembling

```
-A SomeChain SomeActions Target
```

For example

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

You can create the same rule by using iptables command with

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly flush or remove all chains except for one. However, since it's straightforward to list the chains a short combination of options will suffice

List the chains

```
iptables -nL | awk '$1 == "Chain" { print $2 }'

INPUT
FORWARD
OUTPUT
f2b-iptables-log
f2b-recidive
f2b-sshd
```

Flush all except for `INPUT` (remove `echo` when you're sure it works for you):

```
iptables -nL |
    awk -v keep=INPUT '$1 == "Chain" && $2 != keep { system("echo iptables -F " $2) }'
```